Term for propositions having pathos-related force
I have a question in regards to terminology in argumentation and rhetoric. If a proposition having an ethos-related force can be called "ethotic", what should we call a proposition having a pathos-related force? Is "pathetic" the right word here?

Ethotic is rhetorical terminology. It is used in the literature like in this work. Pathetic is indeed used in technical literature such as this work. From the article:

Pathetic argument, or argument based on pathos, persuades by appealing to the emotions of the reader or listener. In Aristotle's classic treatment, it exists in parallel to logical argument, which appeals to deductive or inductive reasoning, and ethical argument, which appeals to the character of the speaker. Pathetic argument is common in constitutional law, as in other practical discourse-think of "Poor Joshua!"- but existing accounts of constitutional practice do not provide resources for understanding the place of and limitations upon such appeals when they appear in judicial opinions.

Obviously, in common discourse, pathetic is intended as a slur so context and knowing your audience matter.
